# Rounding Pixel Error

Tags: css, alignment, pixel, rounding

Having trouble with a layout going out of alignment by 1 pixel while resizing the browser in Safari. I have a vertically repeating background with a container that includes a header div and a wrapper containing the page content.You can view the site here: [view here](http://isimpledev.singulareditions.com)

Here is some of the CSS:

```css
body {color: #666666; background: #f2f2f2 url('../images/blue/background_site.gif') repeat-y center center; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#Container {
    width: 960px;
    border-collapse: collapse;  
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#Header {height: 98px; background: url('../images/blue/background_header.gif') repeat-x bottom left; margin-bottom: 20px;}
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle demonstrating your problem.  The question isn't clear right now

Comment: Updated with link to development site.

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot with the problematic area circled?

Comment: If you resize the browser left-right in Safari, you can see the pixels shift by 1 between the gold content background and the repeating drop shadow background.

Answer (score -1):

Ended up using a Javascript hack, it works but isn't the best solution.